# Bug bizarro em player só acontece no chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, lista, firefox, google-chrome

Estou fazendo um site com playlist de música tudo funciona tudo bem no meu pc em todos os navegadores, mas quando eu subo para o servidor, acontece algo bizarro, onde somente no google chrome depois que eu toco 6 músicas não importando a ordem ele simplesmente não toca mais, sendo que no firefox e no ie funciona perfeitamente tanto na internet quanto localhost.

Eu até pensei que era erro do javascript, mas como só daria esse erro no servidor? e só no chrome? então descartei essa hipótese. Também descartei a hipótese de erros em escrita por que senão nos outros também dava o mesmo erro e então fiquei meio perdido não sei o que fazer, pois nunca vi um erro desse.

O link para o site está aqui http://www.twinshark.com.br/clientes/sambadedom/

OBS:não colei o javascript pois ele é mto grande

Comment: Meu chute: Por algum motivo suas conexões estão ficando abertas e você está batendo no limite de 6 conexões simultâneas por domínio: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285567.

Comment: No console estão aparecendo vários erros similares a esse: `www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED`.

Comment: Então vc acha que é culpa do servidor? Quanto ao erros sinceramente não entendo mto de debugar esses erros eu sei usar o javascript até certo ponto agora debugar só css3 e HTML5

Comment: Acho que é um erro de configuração ou um bug na biblioteca que você está utilizando. Talvez você consiga maiores informações no Wiki / fórum ou bug tracker deles.

Comment: no final das contas o erro é era do meu próprio chrome

Comment: A mesma coisa acontece nos dois Chromes que tenho instalado (v 39 no Windows e openSUSE).